# Why does the performance of this non-matching pattern scale with the size of the search space?

Tags: c++, regex

I have code like the following:

```
#include <regex>

int main()
{
   char buf[35000] = {};
   auto begin = std::cbegin(buf), end = std::cend(buf);

   std::cmatch groups;
   std::regex::flag_type flags = std::regex_constants::ECMAScript;
   std::regex re(R"REGEX(^[\x02-\x7f]\0..[\x01-\x0c]\0..\0\0)REGEX", flags);
   std::regex_search(begin, end, groups, re);
}
```

… and noticed that it performed suspiciously slowly.

Investigating, I plugged in different values for that buffer size, and found that [the search gets slower as the buffer expands](http://quick-bench.com/KuxSIwPlBuu697YuunlU4ZaEVxI):

[image: quick-bench.com graph showing the behaviour when unmatching, with various input sizes]

*(small=100, large=35000, huge=100000; "unanchored" is with `^` omitted from the pattern)*

The results are [as I'd expect](http://quick-bench.com/wvFDqcMEgra6NZM1VSxjO5PhKOs) if I provide an input that actually matches the pattern:

[image: quick-bench.com graph showing the behaviour when matching, with various input sizes]

`std::regex` is not in multiline mode by default (right?), so I'd have thought that anchor (`^`) would have prevented such shenanigans. Pattern not found at the start of the search string? Return no match, job done.

Seems to happen with both libc++ and libstdc++.

What am I missing about this? What's causing it?

Obvious workarounds include giving `std::regex_search` just a prefix of the buffer (a prefix large enough to encompass all possible matches but no more than necessary), or just examining the string in some other way. But I'm curious.

---

FWIW, with a near-equivalent JavaScript testcase, Safari 12.0 on OSX [works as I'd expect](https://jsperf.com/anchored-nonmatching-regex/1), with only a very small variation between the three searches (which I'm attributing to random factors) and no obvious pattern:

[image: jsperf.com graph showing that JavaScript does what I'd expect]

---

For the avoidance of doubt, I retested with a regex as simple as `^what` and [got the same results](http://quick-bench.com/CwleYYPpHed8VMPZSoij7Ku63AU). Might update the above examples later for coherence if I can work up the motivation. :)

Comment: What the regex is supposed to match and what are those `REGEX` literals?

Comment: @revo: `R"REGEX(...)REGEX"` is a _raw string literal_ with [arbitrarily chosen] delimiter "REGEX" - it allows me to write this regex without double-backslashing everything. Could also have been `"^[\\x02-\\x7f]\\0..[\\x01-\\x0c]\\0..\\0\\0"`. Read more [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)

Comment: I'm not sure there is any shortcut when the inner machine state is all null. You could have an "or" without a `^` that would impede implementing any simple shorcut like that.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Hmm not sure what you mean? I'm surprised that the impl doesn't just stop looking after the first character (and therefore time taken would not scale with input size) as the pattern cannot possibly match if `'\x02'` (or alternative up to `'\x07'`) doesn't lead. I can't work out where my logic has gone wrong! Am I being massively overoptimistic about this kind of thing?

Comment: But you could have a regex saying match the beginning of the string, or something else later. And you have to be able to create a mechanism that says that if the machine state is empty of "1" (matched something), then you bail out. I think it's quite difficult to implement from the time I had to implement a simpler such mechanism (without the full current grammar).

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher But I don't. I have a regex with an unconditional `^` at the start of it :( What is the engine doing when it's looking through the remainder of the buffer? What's it looking for?

Comment: I didn't ask about string literals I said why do you have `REGEX` literals there? which you answered they are delimiters. But `REGEX(^` is never going to produce a match because `^` asserts beginning of input string or a position preceding a newline character. You didn't consider this in your regex.

Comment: It's unrolling the full string, updating the machine state. It's an unconditional `^`, I agree, but it may not be that simple to recognize this and catch the pattern (i.e. unconditional `^` with a global false state). I may be wrong of course.

Comment: @revo: _"didn't ask about string literals I said why do you have REGEX literals there?"_ But that's the answer. It's part of the string literal.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Hmm. :(

Comment: By that question I was trying to find out what you mean by that regex since it didn't seem to me a well-constructed one at the first glance.

Comment: [Random example from the web](https://www.loggly.com/blog/five-invaluable-techniques-to-improve-regex-performance/) of people expecting the same as I expected: _"Regex 2 of course runs much faster on non-matching input because it throws out the non-matching input almost immediately. In short, if you can use an anchor or a boundary, then you should because they can pretty much only help the performance of your regex."_

Comment: @revo: I see. The regex itself is `/^[\x02-\x7f]\0..[\x01-\x0c]\0..\0\0/` and I believe it's valid. I could have picked a simpler one on reflection (I copied it from my codebase and didn't want to re-run the benchmarks :P).

Comment: Did you try the new compile time "version" that was presented at cppcon in 2018? It may have better shortcuts?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Funnily enough a colleague suggested this too! I'm hoping to find time to give it a go, though tbh I'm hoping to be able to make the built-in implementation work to my expectations

Comment: Is providing the same buffer size (`LargeBufSize`) for all methods intentional in your second benchmark?

Comment: @revo .... whoops! Will correct. It isn't making a difference to the results though. Thanks for reporting it ☺️

Comment: Interestingly visual studio 2017 does better, large is 6.5 times slower, huge is 16.9 times slower than small

Comment: @AlanBirtles The fact that all three mainstream implementations are scaling like this then (although nice to hear that VS is better) where JS isn't at all, makes me wonder again whether I'm misunderstanding the default `std::regex` flags. This _isn't_ in multiline mode, right?

Comment: plus one for effort alone, those are some great graphs (also nice mvce)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply because libstdc++ and libc++ do not implement such optimization.

The following is the [main part](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/464ac146f6d2aaab847f653edde3ae84a8366c94/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/regex_executor.tcc#L37-L54) of libstdc++'s implementation of `regex_search`:

```
template<typename _BiIter, typename _Alloc, typename _TraitsT,
     bool __dfs_mode>
  bool _Executor<_BiIter, _Alloc, _TraitsT, __dfs_mode>::
  _M_search()
  {
    if (_M_search_from_first())
      return true;
    if (_M_flags & regex_constants::match_continuous)
      return false;
    _M_flags |= regex_constants::match_prev_avail;
    while (_M_begin != _M_end)
    {
      ++_M_begin;
      if (_M_search_from_first())
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

So it does traverse the whole range even if the regular expression contains `^`.

So is [libc++'s implementation](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/regex#L5859-L5897).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just to add, I'm not quite ready to classify this as an "optimization", so much as "a sensible way to do this". Is the engine _really_ searching all 35,000 bytes for "a character that's at the start of the string"? That's crazy! Seems like the implementation needs to be able to fail-fast if it's to be fit for purpose. I'm tempted to raise bugs for this but would like people to confirm that I'm not being unreasonable first.

Answer (score 0):

I am now considering this to be a quality of implementation issue that affects all three toolchains.

Bugs raised:

- [libstdc++ bug 88947](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88947)

  - Status: confirmed by dev team
- [libc++ bug 40390](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40390)

  - Status: unconfirmed
- [Visual Studio bug 432178](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/432178/regex-match-doesnt-fail-early-when-given-a-non-mat.html)

  - Status: unconfirmed