# Find only first std::regex match efficiently

Tags: c++, regex, c++17, lexer

I'm trying to find an efficient way to greedily find the first match for a `std::regex` without analyzing the whole input.

My specific problem is that I wrote a hand made lexer and I'm trying to provide rules to parse common literal values (eg. a numeric value).

So suppose a simple let's say

```
std::regex integralRegex = std::regex("([+-]?[1-9]*[0-9]+)");
```

Is there a way to find the longest match starting from the beginning of input without scanning all of it? It looks like `std::regex_match` tries to match the whole input while `std::regex_search` forcefully finds all matches.

Maybe I'm missing a trivial overload for my purpose but I can't find an efficient solution to the problem.

Just to clarify the question: I'm not interested in stopping after first sub-match and ignore the remainder of input but for an input like `"51+12*3"` I'd like something that finds first `51` match and then stops, ignoring whatever is after.

Comment: Regex can't match the longest or shortest match. You need to match all occurrences and then use other language means to find the longest one. Or, when iterating, rewrite the result with the longer match.

Comment: How can you ever find the longest matching string without viewing the whole string?

Comment: There was a similar question here recently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54237547/why-does-the-performance-of-this-non-matching-pattern-scale-with-the-size-of-the

Comment: The problem is not finding all occurrences of the first contiguous match, that's fine, the problem is that in a circumstance like "1234 foo bar 1234 1234" I'd like to stop the search after the first series of matches ends (so after first 1234).

Comment: And the std::regex implementation doesn't do so (see the link I sent, the answer is tehre).

Comment: can you split the input and apply the regex to parts?

Comment: I know that Regular Expression are cool, but people are tend to overuse them.  IMO this is the case where it shouldn't be used since this is classic parsing problem. RE are slow (especially when lots of repetitions are in use), but a good thing about them is: they are configurable. So when RE is hard coded it should not be used.

Comment: @MarekR: let me decide when I want to use regex for a lexer or not, I wrote many standard automaton lexers but in this specific circumstance my requirements fit regex usage, the problem is that the API is lacking.

Comment: Jack, I think Marek is pointing out your issue is a common one: "Hey, I had a problem.  So I tried to solve it with regex.  Now I have two problems, the original problem and this regex issue that is really annoying.  Help!"  Don't get me wrong, I love regex... for the purpose of typing into a vi/sed/awk/python/perl script to do on-off mass editing that I can audit afterwards.

Comment: @Jack I think you can skip the `[1-9]*` part, leaving only `[+-]?[0-9]+` to get the same result as your current regex.

Answer (score 2):

First of all `[+-]?[1-9]?[0-9]+` I think it does the same think, but should be a bit faster. Or you intend to use something like this: `[+-]?[1-9][0-9]*|0` (zero without sign or number not starting with zero).

Secondly C++ provides regular expression iterator:

```
const std::string s = "51+12*3";

std::regex number_regex("[+-]?[1-9]?[0-9]+");
auto words_begin = 
    std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), number_regex);
auto words_end = std::sregex_iterator();

std::cout << "Found " 
          << std::distance(words_begin, words_end) 
          << " numbers:\n";

for (std::sregex_iterator i = words_begin; i != words_end; ++i) {
    std::smatch match = *i;                                                 
    std::string match_str = match.str(); 
    std::cout << match_str << '\n';
}
```

And looks like this is what you need.

https://wandbox.org/permlink/tkaAfIslkWeY2poo